# Sorting array into array new based on string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort a JSON into multiple arrays based on `type`, my current json is:

```
// current json file:
{
    "res": [
        {
            "type" : "stream",
            "price" : "3.99",
            "id" : "13nee"
        },
        {
            "type" : "stream",
            "price" : "2.99",
            "id" : "8ejwj"
        },
        {
            "type" : "buy",
            "price" : "3.99".
            "id" : "9akwk"
        },      
        ...
    ]
}
```

I'm looking to sort it into multiple arrays by `type` like below:

```
var sorted = {
    "stream" : [
        {
            "price" : "2.99",
            "id" : "8ejwj"
        },
        {
            "price" : ".99",
            "id" : "13nee"
        },

        ... // other objects with type: "stream"
    ],
    "buy" : [
        {
            "price" : "3.99".
            "id" : "9akwk"
        },
        ... // other objects with type: "buy"
    ]
}
```

I've tried it, but the only solution I can think of is by cases - run if loop, if case matches type, then push object to array. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = {};
var i = 0;

for(i; i < res.length; i += 1){
    var resItem = res[i];
    if(items.hasOwnProperty(resItem.type)){
       items[resItem.type].push({price:resItem.price, id:resItem.id});
    } else {
        items[resItem.type] = [{price:resItem.price, id:resItem.id}];
    }
}
```

The properties on JavaScript objects are hashed, so you can dynamically match and generate new objects like above. If you want to apply a well ordering sort, you'll need to apply it to the arrays of the newly generated items object.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : 
Convert the JSON to a jquery object :

```
var x = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString );
```

Step 2: 
Use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library's _.groupBy to group :

```
_.groupBy(x,'type');
```

There might be some adjustment you need to do for x being array or object.

Edit :
You don't need step1. Just do :

```
sorted = _.groupBy(json.res,'type');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with ECMA5. This performs, generically, the `sort` and `reduce` that you have indicated in your question, so you can add more fields to your data without having to change the routine. It also leaves your original data intact.

Javascript

```
var original = {
    'res': [{
            'type': 'stream',
            'price': '3.99',
             'id': '13nee'
        }, {
            'type': 'stream',
            'price': '2.99',
            'id': '8ejwj'
        }, {
            'type': 'buy',
            'price': '3.99',
            'id': '9akwk'
        }]
    },
    sorted = {};

original.res.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
    a = +(a.price);
    b = +(b.price);

    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}).reduce(function (acc, element) {
    if (!acc[element.type]) {
        acc[element.type] = [];
    }

    acc[element.type].push(Object.keys(element).filter(function (name) {
        return name !== 'type';
    }).reduce(function (prev, name) {
        prev[name] = element[name];

        return prev;
    }, {}));

    return acc;
}, sorted);

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

Output

```
{
    "stream": [{
        "price": "2.99",
        "id": "8ejwj"
    }, {
        "price": "3.99",
        "id": "13nee"
    }],
    "buy": [{
        "price": "3.99",
        "id": "9akwk"
    }]
}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/u4Jdq/)